# Can't find Memory inspector in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/memory-inspector/) article it is shown how to open the Memory Inspector, but I don't see it in my Chrome 90.0.4430.93. According to the article it should look like this:[image]
But in my case I don't see any "Reveal in Memory Inspector panel" item:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I see it in Chrome Canary so I guess it's not exposed in v90.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, I found it in Canary as well, it wasn't clear from the article that the memory inspector is not in stable release yet (https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-91/#memory-inspector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the feature is available from Chrome 91 (https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-91/#memory-inspector).

At the moment, official Chrome release is 90. You can download Chrome Beta or Chrome Canary to use that feature!